# How to kill a MySQL query with Node.js without disconnecting?

Tags: mysql, node.js, kill-process

**Context:**
I'm building a web application that calls data from a large db (several millions of rows for table); sometimes a user can change his mind and call for new data before the query on the db has been completed.

**Technical question:**
I tried to kill the query in this cases using:

```
app.get("/data", function(req, res) {
    if (req.query.killQuery == "true") {
        con.query("KILL \"" + threadId + "\"", function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("I have interrupted the executing query for a new request");
            giveData(req, res); //The function that will execute a new query
        }); 
        return;
    }
    giveData(req, res); //The function that will execute a new query
});
```

Now I have several doubts about this code:

- I had to use a second connection to kill the thread of the first, since the first was unable to perform new queries before the first was completed. Is this a Node.js behaviour or is it the right way to do this kind of things?
- The `KILL thread_id` statement closes the whole connection instead of stopping the single query. Again, is it Node.js behaviour, or is it MySQL itself? Should I really disconnect and reconnect to stop a query and start with an other?

Comment: How did you find the query thread id with nodejs? It's just the connection thread id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a modern version of MySQL, you can use `KILL QUERY <threadId>` instead which will *only* kill the currently executing query on that connection but leave the connection intact.

Comment: Wonderful *-* one word to make a much better code! Thank you a lot =)

Comment: how do i get the <threadId> if my query is still running ?

Comment: @Hanna The mysql server sends the thread ID to clients upon connecting to the server. How you obtain that value depends entirely on the library you're using. Refer to the library's documentation.